# Activating a conda environment overrides the rc file for my shell

Tags: bash, conda, zshrc, rc

Often when using conda environments, the environment variables set in my rc file are overwritten (experienced with both bash as zsh), particularly my `$PATH` variable.  It does not always happen though; I just experienced this, then tried to reproduce it but the second time it did not happen.

After activating the conda environment (`source activate py35`) I can resource my rc file (`source ~/.zshrc`) to recover my environment variables but can I avoid this extra step?

Comment: Are you sourcing the environment through another script i.e. may be in a sub-shell? That could be a reason why your environment is lost after the sub-shell exits.

Comment: @Inian, I am not using a script to source the conda environment, just my shell.